# Difficulties creating a iterative function

Tags: python, recursion, for-loop

I need some clever way of turning this into a recurse function. D is a dictionary with keys, that need to match the a,b,c's..

The D's keys are just numbers in random order - and they need to be sorted in a specific order and put in a list, which the function "findKeyForLargestValue" makes them.

This is my primitive function (does not work for all types of dictionaries)

```
def findOrder(name,D):
    Order=[name]
    a=findKeyForLargestValue(D[name])
    b=findKeyForLargestValue(D[a])
    c=findKeyForLargestValue(D[b])
    d=findKeyForLargestValue(D[c])
    e=findKeyForLargestValue(D[d])
    f=findKeyForLargestValue(D[e])
    Order.append(a)
    Order.append(b)
    Order.append(c)
    Order.append(d)
    Order.append(e)
    Order.append(f)
    return Order
```

The output needs to be a list like this:

```
['4', '2', '5', '1', '6', '3']
```

And it needs to be able to loop over any type of D.

Comment: your description of what you want to achieve is unclear.

Comment: If I understand what your after you're probably better off with an iterative function.

Comment: yes I want a iterative function, but I'm not sure how to get it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean at all. Do you want a sorted list of the values? A list of the values sorted by key? A list of keys sorted by the value of the associated items?

Comment: How do you get a, b, c, d, e, f, etc. ?

Comment: And could you paste your function `findKeyForLargestValue()`?

Comment: and also please post the initial contents of the D. it is always good to post INPUT CODE and EXPECTED OUTPUT when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this recursive function cam help you...

```
Order = []

def findOrder(name, D):
    Order.append(name)
    try:
        other = findKeyForLargestValue(D[name])
    except:
        return
    findOrder(other, D)

findOrder(name, D)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to `findOrder` that tells it how many times to iterate, then do this:

```
def findOrder(name, D, count):
    Order = [name]
    for i in range(count):
        name = findKeyForLargestValue(D[name])
        Order.append(name)
    return Order
```

This should do what you want (if I'm not misunderstanding the question)

Answer (score 0):

```
def findOrder(name,D):
    myList = [name]
    for i in xrange(6): 
        new = findKeyForLargestValue(D[myList[-1]])
        myList.append(new)
    return myList
```